# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object CURL Result?

Tags: php, arrays, json, object, curl

Hi I'm trying to mess around with an API.
But I keep getting this strange error and I have searched the internet but I can't seem to fix it while trying to read about the error.

I'm getting this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 22

Here is line 17 to 28 of index.php

```
$server = "localhost:8087";
$player = $_SESSION['username'];
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
$params = array("Command" => "AccountsPassword", "Player" => $player, ":", "PW" => $password);
$api = Poker_API($params);
if ($api -> Result != "Ok") die($api -> Error . "<br/>" . "Go to the homepage to try again.");
if ($api -> Verified != "Yes") die("Password is incorrect. Go to the homepage to try again.");
$params = array("Command" => "AccountsSessionKey", "Player" => $player);
$api = Poker_API($params);
if ($api -> Result != "Ok") die($api -> Error . "<br/>" . "Go to the homepage to try again.");
$key = $api -> SessionKey;
$src = $server . "/?LoginName=" . $player . "&amp;SessionKey=" . $key;
```

and here is the api.php

```
<?php
  $url = "localhost:8087/api";              // Put your API path here
  $pw = "Removed";                  // put your API password here

  function Poker_API($params)
  {
    global $url, $pw;
    $params['Password'] = $pw;
    $params['JSON'] = 'Yes';
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_errno($curl)) $obj = (object) array('Result' => 'Error', 'Error' => curl_error($curl)); 
    else if (empty($response)) $obj = (object) array('Result' => 'Error', 'Error' => 'Connection failed'); 
    else $obj = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($curl);
    print_r($response);
    //echo implode($params);
    return $obj;
    }

?>
```

Comment: this `$obj = json_decode($response, true);` returns an associated array instead of an object. Ditch the `true` and you will receive an object (unless there's a json error)

Comment: Goodness, thank you it works!

Answer (score 1):

Notice in not an error.
This probably happens when you've got no errors, because you are returning array in this line:

```
else $obj = json_decode($response, true);
```

True, as a second parameter, forces this function to return associative array. So, you have no object to call.

Comment: and if it is a malformed json?

Comment: @Cemal then `json_decode()` returns `null`. The error can be found in [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: Then he will get null as a return value. This is why I wrote 'probably'. Of course it should be handled better.

Comment: indeed it should be, however if you're writing an answer here, IMHO you should actually fix the problem. This kind of short corrections should be placed into comments section, unless it's presented as a whole.

Comment: @Cemal Yes, your are absolutely right. However my reputation is below 50, so I cannot comment on main post.

Comment: My apologies then. Didn't notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these 2 lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Why should one do that? Could you explain what these lines do?